# Integration of Particle Motion

Tags: integration, physics

All. Looking for some help with the following integration.

If the acceleration of a particle is given as

$$ a(t) = \frac{dv(t)}{dt} = k(1+3x^2(t))  $$

where $k$ is constant (and $ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = v(t) $), then how am I able to solve for $v(t)$?

The hint provided said to use an integrating factor but I'm not sure I'm able to put it in the required form of

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y(x) = q(x) $$

Or, at least, it isn't obvious to me.

Before that I tried...

$$ \frac{dv(t)}{dt} = k(1+3x^2(t)) $$

$$ \int \frac{dv(t)}{dt} dt = \int k(1+3x^2(t)) dt $$

$$ v(t) = kt + 3k\int x^2(t)dt $$

And now I'm stuck here... Any help would be appreciated; I'm hoping it's a simple mistake I can chalk up to being under caffeinated. :) Thanks!

Comment: Use $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = v \frac{dv}{dx}$ to solve for $v(x)$ , then integrate with respect to time to get $x(t)$

Comment: @WW1 Ah, yes; thank you! No idea why an integrating factor was suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WW1 pointed before, make

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}v=k(1+3x^2).$$

Now, you have a separable differential equation that you can solve easily integrating

$$\int vdv=\int k(1+x^2),$$

$$\frac{v^2}{2}=k(x+x^3)+c.$$

Then,

$$v(t)=\pm \sqrt{kx(1+x^2(t))+c}$$